# MongoDB Stats for a particular search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I'd like to find a function within the `MongoDB` shell that will let me see how many items are in a particular query.

For instance, I want to do something akin to:

```
 db.collection.find({category: "Cupcakes"}).stats()
```

and see count, file size, that sort of thing.

In `MongoJS` and other front-end implementations of `MongoDb` a query returns an object that you can perform a `.length` method on, like:

```
 db.collection.find({category: "Cupcakes"}, function(err, records){
       console.log(records.length); // Shows how many records are in the search field
 });
```

Any way to do something similar in the shell itself? Would be insanely useful but I can't find any docs or mention anywhere of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is [count()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/). All you need is to do:  `db.collection.find({category: "Cupcakes"}).count()`.

Or as pointed by Stennie you can also use `db.collection.count({category: "Cupcakes"})`

Comment: Well that was embarrassingly simple! Don't know how I haven't come across this before.

Comment: I did not know that you can do stats on the cursor. And in my shell it is rising the error. P.S. this is ok, just use google more often.

Comment: You can't, that was just an example of what I wanted to do. I tried googling it but all I could find were things related to `stats()`

Comment: Oh, sorry have not read it properly. P.S. if the answer fully answers your question, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Was just waiting for the 12min window to finish before I could accept :)

Comment: As a shortcut, you can also provide criteria to count() in the `mongo` shell. So `db.collection.count({category: "Cupcakes"})` is equivalent to `db.collection.find({category: "Cupcakes"}).count()` but a few characters less typing ;-).