# Mongodb size(not count)/stats of a find query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB and I wish to find the data volume (in GiB) for a particular key.

For example, with `db.collection.stats()` I can find the size of the entire collection(for instance 100 GiB)

All documents in mongo have a `org_id` key. I want to find the volume of data occupied by the `org_id`

```
db.collection.find({org_id : 1}) # Find it's size
db.collection.find({org_id : 2}) # This one's too
...
...
#so on
```

I've already seen [MongoDB Stats for a particular search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230499/mongodb-stats-for-a-particular-search) but it only asks for count of documents and not the volume of data. How do go about finding this in mongo shell ?

Comment: There is no such method really, and actually with very good reason. You can see `avgObjSize` and various other "statistics" with `.stats()`. But as for a "field", then you could use the "count" and apply that to the "size" of the BSON type. But there is no such function because MongoDB is "schemaless", and there is **no constraint** that says a particular property **must** be of a certain type. So they might be true for your case when you know the property is always of a certain type, but as a generalization then that presumption would not always be true. By design.

Comment: And to "count" presence of a field as opposed to the matching documents to a condition,  use `.find({ "org_id": { "$exists": true } })`